# JavaFX not included in OpenJDK8?

Tags: java, javafx

Based on this question [Migrate to openJDK 13 and openJFX 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367850/migrate-to-openjdk-13-and-openjfx-13) I someone recommended to compile with OpenJDK8 in order to be compatible with JRE8 to run the program. I used Oracle JDK8 with JavaFX but I can't find JavaFX in OpenJDK8 https://devdocs.io/openjdk~8/

So how am I supposed to compile it since openJFX is only available for OpenJDK11+

Comment: There are a few different [JDKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) available. Some include _JavaFX_ and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

Idk why but this really took me some time to find a JDK8 with JavaFX included..

ZuluFX8
https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk